# jQuery UI Auto complete not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my jQuery UI Auto complete not working and showing:(

This is the code for Html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Site classificados</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/css2.css'> 
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script> 
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script> 
<script src='js/js.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='text' align='center' value='".$query."' name='q'></input>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code for script:

```
    <script>
var availableTutorials = [
               'ActionScript',
               'Boostrap',
               'C',
               'C++',
            ];
$('input').autocomplete({
        source: availableTutorials,
        minLength: 1
});  
</script>
```

Everytime i press "A" dont show me Action Script, and same for the B, don't show Bootstrap

I tried with a PHP Making a Sql Query, but not working/showing.

Comment: Could you show us the HTML as well since HTML is tagged. we need to see how this is being scripted in the DOM so we can look at that.

Comment: Ok bro, i edited, f5 and see it

Comment: Ok see answer, I made a few edits to it after you put the HTML on the code.

Comment: Console Logs / Errors ?

Comment: @MatheusSantos You are trying to initialize before html rendering. Put the code for initialization of Auto complete inside `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a class or ID to your input element, I usually use classes, but sometimes especially with input's I use ID's.

Your $('input').autocomplete . . . should be changed to either $('#input').autocomplete . . . or $('.input').autocomplete. Also the minLength is not needed because the default value is "1 "already.

Finally the real issue is that you didn't put this in a function so the page sees the script but it doesn't know what to do with it.

---

## The Code

### HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Site classificados</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/css2.css'> 
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script> 
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script> 
<script src='js/js.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--added the "ID" attribute to this input element and set the value to "input" for simplicity-->
<input type='text' align='center' value='".$query."' name='q' id="input"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

## JavaScript

```
$(function() { // add the start function script here
    var availableTutorials = [
        'ActionScript',
        'Boostrap',
        'C',
        'C++',
    ];
    $('#input').autocomplete({ // I put the #input here but you can 
                               // also put .input 
        source: availableTutorials,
        minLength: 1
    });
}); // end the function here
```

Answer (score 0):

1-/ check your links ( src="...." )
it working here

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var availableTags = [

          'ActionScript',
          'Boostrap',
          'C',
          'C++',

        ];
        $("input").autocomplete({
          source: availableTags,
          minLength: 1
        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="ui-widget">
      <input type="text">
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: changing the variable name on both sides doesn't really fix the issue. You put the script into a function, which is why it works here and not on the original code.